# What is $\pi_3(S^2\times S^1)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

What is the third  [homotopy group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) of $S^2\times S^1$? Here $S^n$ means the $n$-dimensional sphere.

I am a physicist and did not take courses on too mathematical topics. I just need a fact of this in a recent research project. I thought some mathematicians or students from the mathematical department may know the result. Details on derivation could be skipped (for me).

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ArcticChar I did not attempt to calculate it, sorry. I am a physicist and did not take courses on too mathematical topics. I just need a fact of this in a recent research project. I thought some mathematicians or students from the mathematical department may know the result. Details on derivation could be skipped (for me).

Comment: Let me suggest you reread our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). You might have observed that posts which simply state a problem, without any other context such as what you might of tried, can quickly get closed.

Comment: Okay, that's $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We may identify: $$\pi_3(S^2\times S^1)\cong \pi_3(S^2)\oplus \pi_3(S^1),$$
via projection onto the two factors.

We know $\pi_3(S^1)\cong \pi_3(\mathbb{R})$ as this is unchanged by passing to the universal cover. As $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, we get $\pi_3(\mathbb{R})=0$.

For the other factor, $\pi_3(S^2)\cong \pi_3(S^3)$, via the long exact sequence associated to the Hopf fibration, and using the fact that the second and third homotopy groups of the fiber $S^1$ are trivial (for the reason given above):

$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\to&\pi_3(S^1)\cong 0& \to& \pi_3(S^3)&\to&\pi_3(S^2)\\
\to&\pi_2(S^1)\cong0&\to
\end{array}
$$

We then have $\pi_3(S^3)\cong H_3(S^3;\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, via the Hurewicz homomorphism.

The net result is $\pi_3(S^2\times S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, with the generator being the Hopf map composed with inclusion: $$S^3\stackrel{h}\to S^2 \hookrightarrow S^2\times S^1.$$

In simple terms, the Hopf map is the map from $$S^3=\{(z,w)|\,\,z\bar{z}+w\bar{w}=1\}\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2,$$ to $$S^2=\{[z:w]|\,\,(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}\},$$
which maps $(z,w)\mapsto [z:w]$.